# How does apple decide whether an app is in-house?

Tags: ios, publish, in-house-distribution

How does apple decide whether an app is in-house? Is there a setting that I need to look into? Apple has rejected my application saying it is an in-house app and I cannot publish that app under Apple Developer Program.

They want me to have Apple Developer Enterprise Program to publish that app. I'll be thankful for any help.

## EDIT: Here is the message from Apple

*We found that your app is an in-house app, intended for employees or members of your organization. As such, it is not appropriate for the App Store.*

*For information on distributing proprietary, in-house apps, please refer to the iOS Developer Enterprise Program.*

*If you cannot - or choose not to - revise your app to be in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines, you may wish to build an HTML5 web app instead. You can distribute web apps directly on your web site; the App Store does not accept or distribute web apps.*

*HTML5 is the major new version of HTML and enables audio and video to play natively in the browser without requiring proprietary plug-ins. Using HTML5, web apps can look and behave like native iPhone and iPad apps, and using HTML5's Offline Application Cache, a web app can work even when the device is offline. With web apps, you have flexibility to deliver as much or as little functionality as you desire.*

*To get started with iPhone or iPad web apps, please review the Safari Client-Side Storage and Offline Applications Programming Guide.*

*For a description of the HTML elements and attributes you can use in Safari on iPhone, check out Safari HTML Reference: Introduction.*

Comment: I guess they look at the functionality of your app, the applicable audience and whether it is generally useful.  For example, an app that required authentication against your organisation's Active Directory wouldn't be suitable for the app store (I am not saying this is what your app does, it is just an example).

Comment: Are they correct?

Comment: @Fogmeister The iOS app uses the webview to display the web application. The user can login to the app if the user is already registered to web application.

Comment: Ah, Well web wrapper apps have always been "against the rules". I have seen a few get through the approval process but an app is not just a website wrapped inside an app.

Comment: @Paulw11 The app is generally useful to everyone who have registered to the web application but cannot register using the iOS app, can it be the reason why they rejected?

Comment: Yes, I would say so.

Comment: How can one get to know about the app if I use Enterprise program to publish the app? I'm new to this.

Comment: I still wonder how they decide whether it is in-house app or normal app which can be published in App Store. We didn't select anything fancy to make it in-house.

Comment: Is there any kind login or sorts, then there must be a registration
Processes like these counts, as apple wants your "normal app" to be used by everyone when its in the appstore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess there can be many ways by which Apple can think of in-house apps and one of these can be your App Description. Here is the response from Apple that I received.

> Hello,
>
> Thank you for your response. The Application Description confirms that
>   the app will be used by employees of your company to stay connected
>   and informed of daily tasks and company information. If the app will
>   have an open registration and not limited to the internal use of your
>   company, please take the time to modify the Application Description by
>   providing this clarity and also accurately describe the app's features
>   and functionality available to all users.
>
> Otherwise, the app is not appropriate for the App Store, and it would
>   be best to be distributed via the iOS Developer Enterprise Program.

As @Paulw11 said, Apple can even decide that your app is in-house if it doesn't allow everyone to use and limited to a group of people.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can understand, you are trying to publish your app from your Apple Developer Account which has "Developer Program of 99$" activated. 
But to publish in house application, you would require an **iOS Developer Enterprise Program** which costs 299 $ yearly.
You have to enrol yourself to that and then publish the app via, your Enterprise program

Please respond accordingly if your intend was NOT to release your app as in-house application, will edit the answer accordingly

Comment: I understand the difference between two but how it is decided that it is inhouse-app or normal app which can be published in App Store

Comment: Apple explained it in their reply: "_We found that your app is an in-house app, intended for employees or members of your organization_".  To be in the app store, your app has to be (potentially) useful to everyone.

Comment: Yes, thats what i commented in OP's question. I think OP should revisit the app's availability to everyone from scratch to use the app, and also the app's architecture in terms of end user again

Comment: It was not build to be used as in-house app, we need this app to the store.

Comment: There must be some feature, that in the mind of Apple, normal people from scratch cant use your app, like some sort of login or any other feature. I would also check the hybrid approach, as apple seems to complain on that.